# How could Eclipse MAT use multiple CPU?

Tags: eclipse, mat

It seems that Eclipse MAT couldn't use Multiple CPU, although I have 24CPUs, I searched the Google for a long time, but now anwser...
Or is there any better tools?

Comment: A long time coming, but I have been contributing some work to allow this. It is improving, feedback and improvements welcome.

Comment: @jasonk is this option to use multiple cores available now?

Comment: I put in a few more recently that should come out with 1.16, when it's released. You can get the Nightly build to pick it up from the MAT website. Feedback welcome if you see specific areas/phases that are more problematic, open a ticket and/or @ me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, In the windows, there is no direct way to do this. But what we do is to work around this by utilizing the processor affinity feature of the windows.   Steps are as given below:

- open Windows Task Manager (Ctrl + shift + Esc)
- On the Processes tab, at the bottom click on Show processes from all users button.
- Right click the process (MemoryAnalyzer.exe) whose processor affinity you want to change and choose Set Affinity. Now Check the CPU(s) that you want the process (application) to run on and click OK. Alternatively if you want to give all processors we can choose all processor option.

Note:

- There are certain caveats like the Java still dictates when to switch and what to switch. But you will get better results than the partial processor allotment.
- The processor affinity setting lasts as long as an application is open, when you close the application or restart the computer, the affinity returns to the default.
- In some cases all are checked by default this means that it is already using all cpu's and nothing much can be done... :(